# How to filter pandas.DataFrame with two conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

suppose i have a DataFrame like this

```
_data=pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['sam','kalrx','mark','ru']
})
```

and if i want to filter the dataframe with two names, then how can i do it

```
_data.where(_data=='sam' and 'mark')
```

Comment: You want `or` condition not `and` as your name can not be both `sam` and `mark`

Comment: my question can be googled by the people who deosnt know sql, so, let us not close this question,thanks